# Nginx web server on windows 10 not doesn't start localhost

Tags: nginx

Error

```
bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Skype.
Turn the "use port 80" option back on.

It's in settions->advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Change the port in conf\nginx.conf file

from 
 server {
        listen       80;
To :
 server {
        listen       8070;